# nodejs doesn't work in production(Heroku) while perfectly fine in development(in my localhost)

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, axios, cheerio

I am stuck in this code from past one week. I'm building my first project which is youtube/instagram video downloader using vanilla js(bit of jquery)  and nodejs as backend language. I dont know why it is not working in production while working well in development.

I'm just trying to scrape instagram using the link and get the video link so that i can use
this as src value in my video element

*** instaController.js ***

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio')
const axios = require('axios')


exports.download = async function (req, res, next) {
    try {
        const html = await axios({
            method: 'get',
            url: req.body.url
        })
        const $ = cheerio.load(html.data)

        const videoLink = $("meta[property='og:video']").attr("content")
        const poster = $("meta[property='og:image']").attr("content")
        const type = $("meta[property='og:type']").attr("content")
        const site = $("meta[property='og:site_name']").attr("content")
        const description = $("meta[property='og:description']").attr("content")
        res.locals.data = {
            videoLink,
            type,
            site,
            poster,
            description
        }
        next()
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('axiosError:', e.message)
        res.status(200).json({
            error: "Something went wrong"
        })
    }
}
```

***frontendJs.js***

```
const res = await axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: '/download/instagram',
            data: {
                url: input.value
            }
        })
        //console.log(res.data)

        if (!res.data.error) {
              $('#form-elements').html(res.data)
        } else {
            alert('danger', 'Invalid link')
        }
```

*** insta.ejs ***

```
<%if(data.videoLink){%>

    <div class="col-12 mx-auto p-3 p-lg-3 mb-5">
        <h3 class="text-center">Long Press/Right Click the Video to download :)</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 mx-auto p-3 p-lg-3 video">
        <video id="video" src="<%= data.videoLink%>" controls type="<%= data.type%>" poster="<%=data.poster%>"
            class="mx-auto" playsinline></video>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 insta-details p-1 p-lg-3">
        <h2 class="text-center">Info</h2>
        <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center my-4">
            <div class="col">Type</div>
            <div class="col" id="type"><%= data.site%> <%= data.type%></div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <div class="col">Description</div>
            <div class="col" id="desc"><%= data.description%></div>
        </div>
    </div>

<%}else{%>

    <div class="col-12 insta-details  p-1 p-lg-3 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
        <h3 class="text-center">Sorry No Such Video or Video from private account :( </h3>
    </div>

<%}%>
```

But else part of the ejs is returned in production but in my localhost , this same code returns the if part of ejs.I'm very confused!!! Please help me to recover from this situation :( Thanks in advance

Comment: Any errors in your browser javascript console, and does any of said errors have "CORS" mentioned? (just going for the low hanging fruit here)

Comment: yeah, you should try to log the error, if you go in the else block, it means that `res.data.error` is filled.

Comment: They're probably blocking traffic from Heroku

Comment: @pguardiario what is the solution for it sir?

Comment: I don't have one. Residential proxy maybe.

Comment: Finally I've changed the platform from heroku to clever-cloud and it works fine:)